# Git remote -v works but creating new branches it uses the wrong submodules

Tags: git, gitlab

Let me start from the first, We have 20 clients running this same way.  I did not build our current git system but I have inherited it. I did get some good crash course information before the guy left the company.

A few weeks ago, I cloned a repo named `Go-To` from an existing repo `Come-From`. It has 3 branches (master, test, preview) for testing that are pushed and used to view from the web site. We have 3 submodules for this repo. Only one WF1 branch has been created that changes have been pushed to (master, test, preview)
The first issue that came up was that the submodules were not updating. I fixed the git remote -v for the submodules since they were not pointing to the right place when I made the clone. I was able to reset the head and all of the changes worked fine. I had our Web team make changes and push without an issue.

Now to the problem that happened the next day. A different person checked out WF1 and made changes and pushed to (master, test, preview) when this happened it somehow created new submodules for the name Go-To-To-system. Now instead of 3 submodules, I have 6. I reverted to the hotfix on master, test and WF1 we did to test before the issue happened.

running a new git clone from the branches they look right.

```
git clone --recurse-submodules -b preview git@myserver:gitrepos/Go-To.git

cd /go-to/system
git checkout preview
git remote -v       
origin git@myserver:gitrepos/Go-To-system.git (fetch)
origin git@myserver:gitrepos/Go-To-system.git (push)
```

If I create a new branch using the script that was written that works for all of the other clients.
I get this.

```
git remote -v       
origin git@myserver:gitrepos/Go-To-To-system.git (fetch)
origin git@myserver:gitrepos/Go-To-To-system.git (push)
```

Submodules that are right: `Go-To-system`

Submodules that should not exist: `Go-To-To-system`

I have checked all of the remote -v for the branches and they look right. Do I need to fix something else when a new branch is created?

Comment: You reference a script that was written that works...what is that script?

Comment: it asks them the repo and then what branch(WF2). If the script does not find the branch it asks them if they want to create the new branch. After that it does the full checkout of the repo and all of the submodules. Creates new branches if needed.

When they person has finished working on the web changes in eclipse then they run a second script. It asks what repo, branch(WF2), and where they want to push the changes. normally they push to test first. After testing is done then they will push to preview and/or live(master).

Comment: It almost sounds like someone put in the wrong location for the new repo...since what you're showing is a completely different repo, not a different branch

Comment: I think it has something to do with us creating this repo with a - in it. I am trying to understand his scripts and i wonder if the - in the original name Go-To created the issue. 
Somehow now new branches are pointing to the new submodule that is on our gitlab. On the main server where the (live,Test,Pre) folders are located it all look fine. No extra folder or anything.

Comment: Mind pasting the script up here?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on clearing client info form the script and noticed this section in the section for the submodules. after going through the commands this is what is causing our issue. This was the first Client that we used a dash in the name and since the scrips were using the dash to pull the information from the (git remote -v) for the $submodules. It was causing the doubling up of the second part of the name.

if $createrepo
then
        for submodule in "${submodules[@]}"
        do
                cd $submodule;
                remote="$(git remote -v)";
                remote="${remote#*'-'}";
                remote="${remote%%' '*}";

Thanks Kevin Mansel for your help. I think going back through the whole scripts helped me see the issue. Im still learning bash scripting and Git so all of the symbols in the part above i think threw me off the dash.